# Code Behind: Check if property of a control is bound

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, code-behind

I´m looking for a way to check in code behind, if a property of a control has been bound and can´t seem to find the right way to do it. I think I need to get the FieldInfo first (using System.Windows.Controls.Control control in a generic method):

```
FieldInfo te = null;
foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(control))
{
    if (prop.Name.Equals("Visibility"))
    {
        te = control.GetType().GetField(prop.Name + "Property");
        break;
    }
}
```

...does find the PropertyDescriptor, but not the FieldInfo.

```
FieldInfo gg = control.GetType().GetField("Visibility", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo gg1 = control.GetType().GetField("VisibilityProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo gg2 = typeof(Control).GetField("Visibility", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo gg3 = typeof(Control).GetField("VisibilityProperty", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

...all return null as FieldInfo. When the FieldInfo has been found I would like to check if the value has been bound by doing:

```
DependencyProperty dp = (DependencyProperty)field.GetValue(control);
if (control.GetBindingExpression(dp) == null) ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `BindingOperations.GetBinding` to get Binding Object. Like,

```
// textBox3 is an instance of a TextBox
// the TextProperty is the data-bound dependency property
Binding myBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBox3, TextBox.TextProperty);
```

Ref. [How to: Get the Binding Object from a Bound Target Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-get-the-binding-object-from-a-bound-target-property)

Comment: Thanks :-) I´m using a generic method, so I used this: Binding bindingVisibility = BindingOperations.GetBinding(control, Control.VisibilityProperty);